# didSelectItemAt from collectionView not getting called when the collectionView is inside a UITableView row

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

I have a tableView to feature searches. The second row (indexPath.row = 1) has a UICollectionView inside to display elements horizontally.

As these UICollectionView cells will be users, I want to detect clicks on them, which I cannot achieve. I guess there might be something I don't cover since the collectionView is inside a row of a UITableView. I attach an image where the red squares are the collectionView cells inside a row of a table.

[image: Image describing current state of tableView]

Inside my tableView I have:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! RecentUserCell
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: recentTextReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! RecentTextCell
            cell.viewModel = RecentTextCellViewModel(recentText: recentSearchedText[indexPath.row - 1])
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            return cell
        }
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! RecentUserCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

And the RecentUserCell, has a collectionView inside. **The last method, didSelectItemAt, is not getting called, which means I cannot access to a particular user**

```
private let identifier = "collectionCell"

class RecentUserCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    //MARK: - Properties
    private var users = [User]()
        
    public let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        return collectionView
    }()
    
    //MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        fetchUsers()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: identifier)
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    //MARK: - API
    func fetchUsers() {
        UserService.fetchUsers { users in
            self.users = users
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource

extension RecentUserCell: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) //as! UserCollectionViewCell
        //cell.delegate = self
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        //cell.viewModel = UserCellViewModel(user: users[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}

//MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

extension RecentUserCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 70, height: 80)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Selected item at \(indexPath.row)")
    }
}
```

Anyone has an idea of how I can get this method called or what strategy I could use to detect clicks on this UICollectionViewCells?

Comment: Not sure if this is the only issue but when subclassing `UITableViewCell` you should add subviews to its `contentView`.

Comment: Yes @FabioFelici adding contentView.addSubview(myCollectionView) solved the issue. Anywhere I can read about this to understand it better? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is related to adding subviews directly to `UITableViewCell` and not using `contentView`. You can read more about `UITableViewCell` internals [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1)